# Monit all files in directory

Tags: monit

Is there a possibility to run checks on all files in a directory with monit, Without mention every file in this directory by itself?

For example:

> /etc/configurations-to-monitor/
>
> config1
>
> config2
>
> config3

By now I use this in /etc/monit/conf.d/myconfigs:

> check directory myconfigs path /etc/configurations-to-monitor/
>
> if changed timestamp then alert

But there are some bypass possibilities to this construct. So I would like, to run timestamp and checksum-checks on this directory. The goal is to add more configurations to this directory, without touching the monit configuration again.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The solution for all missing features in monit is creating a script which will do the job and monit will just check its return code.

Answer (score 1):

From  monit-general@nongnu.org on 19.11.2014

```
  Hello, using pattern for multiple files monitoring is not supported currently.
  We plan to add this feature.
```